# How can i toggle between any css property on click using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

i am very new to javascript but i need something like suppose i have a white background button when i click it once then its background should change to black and when i click again on it its background should change into white again. means i need to change background of the same button on clicking the same button, please help me, i am really very puzzle and i am also in learning stage of javascript so if you can tell me something more about javascript or any idea beside what i need, i would be thankful to you, thanks.

Comment: I understand you are new to JavaScript, but what have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

You may try something like this

**HTML:**

```
<button class="btn">Toggle Background</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.btn{
    background:#fff;
}

.btn_red{
    background:red;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('btn_red')
   });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/ZL2W6/)

**Vanilla JavaScript :**

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.querySelector('.btn').onclick = function(){
        if(this.className.match('btn_red')) {
            this.className = 'btn';
        }
        else {
            this.className = 'btn btn_red';
        }
    };
};
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/ZL2W6/1/)
There are other ways but these are just some ideas.

Comment: Meanwhile, you can also use `element.classList.toggle("btn_red")` in Vanilla JS. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle).

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery solution would be

http://jsfiddle.net/zMrtL/ (I put the text color to red so that on toggle it won't end up having text black on black i.e. invisible.)

### CSS

```
#div { /* use any selector that matches your desired element */
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#div.dark { /* the "dark" class to be added by jQuery, 
               put your above selector in front to increase specificity */
    background-color: #000;
}
```

About the "specificity" issue, if you don't add `#div` in front of `dark`, the `#div` definition will override the `.dark` definition and the div will remain white, even it is added by jQuery. Look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) or [this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) if you want to know more.

### JavaScript/Jquery

```
// ensure HTML is ready/completely loaded, so that you won't end up 
// binding click to something non-existent (at the time the binding occurs)
// Trying to bind something non-existent will not work because jQuery can never know
// if there is such element in the future, unless you use delegates (far fetched)
$(function(){ 
    // on click, bind the "click" event to your element, and do something
    $('#div').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('dark'); // on click, toggle the class of the element clicked
        // i.e. if the class does not exist, add it, otherwise remove it.
        // in jQuery, "this" is the element clicked/mouse-overed/etc.. i.e. target of the event
        // in functions passed to jQuery event-binding functions.
        // CSS/browsers is smart enough to detect these class changes and apply styles to new elements.
    });
});
```

`#div` means an element with id `div` i.e. `<div id="div"></div>`, as `#` means an element that has the following ID. If you have class instead i.e. `<div class="div"></div>`, use `.div`

Documentations for [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), and [passing a function to jQuery constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)